# How to retrieve ordered data from gcloud datastore (using php)?

Tags: php, gcloud, datastore

I can get data from datastore if I did not use '->order'. Code is here,

```
  $ancestorKey = $datastore->key('usercomment', 'default');
  $query = $datastore->query()
        ->kind('comment')
        ->hasAncestor($ancestorKey)
        ->limit(20);
  $result = $datastore->runQuery($query);
```

but if I add one more line,

```
  $ancestorKey = $datastore->key('usercomment', 'default');
  $query = $datastore->query()
        ->kind('comment')
        ->hasAncestor($ancestorKey)
        ->order('date', Query::ORDER_DESCENDING)
        ->limit(20);
  $result = $datastore->runQuery($query);
```

then, I get nothing. I tried to add a index.yaml file

```
indexes:
- kind: comment
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

still nothing, please help. 
Many thanks

Comment: Is the naming of your kinds and properties exactly the same as it is when you see your kinds and properties in the Cloud console? Are the indexes you create in status=serving?
Other than that I cannot think something else could be wrong. I have created some entities with ancestors, created some indexes and querying them with the order clause successfully.

Comment: Finally, I found out it should be" ->order('date', 'DESCENDING') "instead of "->order('date', Query::ORDER_DESCENDING)", don't know why, but it works. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out it should be

```
->order('date', 'DESCENDING')
```

instead of 
`->order('date', Query::ORDER_DESCENDING)`

don't know why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Datastore **date** fields are in *ascending* order by default.

If you want to query in *descending* order you need to explicitly define index on the date field in *desc* order including all other fields in your query.

Also be sure to check if you are excluding your any field from index while indexing the entity.

If you are sure all these are in *order* then it should work.